# CrashlyticsUploadDistribution task for custom build types

Tags: android, google-fabric, crashlytics-android

**UPDATE:**  Sorry for disturbing anyone, I found the answer myself. I had a disableCrashlytics attribute in my build.gradle for the concrete buikld types, what prevented appropriate gradle task from being generated. 
Sorry for confusion. I'll leave this here maybe will help someone else :)

---

I have a project with multiple flavors and build types. I want to distribute my Beta build with crashlytics (using gradle distribution).
In gradle I can execute task like this

```
crashlyticsUploadDistribution<FLAVOR_NAME>Release
```

But I am not able to distribute apks with any build type except of Release and Debug.
For example, I have customBuildType in my project, and I want to execute

```
crashlyticsUploadDistribution<FLAVOR_NAME><BUILD_TYPE_NAME>
```

such tasks, unfortunately, do not exist.
How can I build custom build types apks for the distribution in this case?

P.S. Build types are different, but the applicationId is the same, since I don't need to make them different.